# Contextily issue with latest version?

Tags: python, installation, contextily

I am currently teaching a python course and those trying to install contextily today are have an issue with the package not being found and/or creating unsolvable package dependencies with Jupyter notebook. I was wondering if anyone else had come across the same issue and had a solution?

Tried install contextily using conda install conda-forge::contextily and cold install contextily but this create python version discrepancies and conflicts with existing packages in the environment.